# THREE.js vertexShader color mix based on height

Tags: javascript, colors, three.js, glsl

How do I set the color to the mesh only when the height is zero?

As for now, i just mixed the colors:

[image]

The problem is that this kind on mixing is not precise. I just want the color blue only when the height is zero (so only inside that red path I made with paint).

I created a custom material for the mesh, like so:

```
material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
                
                      uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.merge([
                      THREE.UniformsLib['lights'],
                      {
                    lightIntensity: {type: 'f', value: 1.0},
                    diffuse: {type: 'c', value: new THREE.Color(0x0000ff)},
                        color0: {
                          value: new THREE.Color("blue")
                        },
                        color1: {
                          value: new THREE.Color("green")
                        },
                        color2: {
                          value: new THREE.Color("brown")
                        },
                        color3: {
                          value: new THREE.Color("black")
                        },
                        bboxMin: {
                          value: geom.boundingBox.min
                        },
                        bboxMax: {
                          value: geom.boundingBox.max
                        }
                
                          }
                        ]),
                      vertexShader: `
                        uniform vec3 bboxMin;
                        uniform vec3 bboxMax;
                        varying vec2 vUv;
                            varying vec3 vPos;
                varying vec3 vNormal;
                        void main() {
                          vPos = (modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0 )).xyz;
                          vNormal = normalMatrix * normal;
                          vUv.y = (position.y - bboxMin.y) / (bboxMax.y - bboxMin.y);
                          gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
                        }
                      `,
                      fragmentShader: `
                        uniform vec3 color1;
                        uniform vec3 color2;
                        uniform vec3 color3;
                        uniform vec3 color0;
                        varying vec2 vUv;
                    
                        uniform vec3 diffuse;
                        varying vec3 vPos;
                        varying vec3 vNormal;

                        struct PointLight {
                          vec3 position;
                          vec3 color;
                        };
                        uniform PointLight pointLights[ NUM_POINT_LIGHTS ];
                        
                        void main() {
                    vec4 addedLights = vec4(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
                      for(int l = 0; l < NUM_POINT_LIGHTS; l++) {
                        vec3 adjustedLight = pointLights[l].position + cameraPosition;
                        vec3 lightDirection = normalize(vPos - adjustedLight);
                        addedLights.rgb += clamp(dot(-lightDirection, vNormal), 0.0, 1.0) * pointLights[l].color;
                      }
                
                                  
                                            gl_FragColor = mix(vec4(mix(mix(mix(color0, color1, vUv.y), color1, vUv.y), mix(color1, color2, vUv.y), vUv.y), 1.0),addedLights, addedLights);
                                            }
                                          `,
                                        lights: true
                                        });
```

Comment: What colour at what height do you want to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `step()` function. [Here's a definition](https://thebookofshaders.com/glossary/?search=step) to help you understand it. Here's how it works:

`float step(float edge, float x)`

- It takes in a constant to declare the `edge`, and `x`, which is your variable.
- If x is below the edge, you get `0`, and if x is above the edge, you get `1`.

Here's a simplified use of it. When height is below 0.2, you'll get blue, and when height is above 0.2, you'll get green.

```glsl
vec3 green = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
vec3 blue  = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

float edge = 0.2;

float colorMix = step(edge, height);
vec3 finalColor = mix(blue, green, colorMix);
```

I picked 0.2 to give the blue band some thickness, otherwise it wouldn't be visible.

Comment: How do I run through the height points* ? The terrain geometry in created from var geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(terreainPoints), and the mesh with a Delaunator. So how do I access the heights from the fragmentShader?

Comment: @NPLS Pass vertex position in a varying, from vertex shader to fragment shader.

Comment: @prisoner849 How do I get the vertex position variable? is it vPos or vUv?

Comment: @NPLS 'vPos`, which is in world coordinates already. It's really intriguing, that you don't know what is what in your shader code.

Comment: I'm learning THREE.sj custom shading, not enough material online to learn it thoroughly

Comment: @NPLS You wrote the code, you should know which variable you're using for the height. It looks like `vUv.y` is already available in your fragment shader, and it's what you're using for the gradients.

Comment: using vUv.y doesn't work ;) that's why I asked

Comment: @Marquizzo Thanks! It works like a charm! I used step(0.01,vUv.y) instead of vUv.y